# Property In Parent Class - Changing Property Name in Child Possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am modifying existing code. We have a base class from which about 10 classes inherit. The base class has `public long Id { get; set; }`. Now is a good time to mention that the children classes are all Entity Framework models, so the Id becomes an auto-generated primary key.

I now need to add tables that will have one-to-one relationships. I was thinking of ways to over-write "Id", but it seems there is nothing - neither abstract or virtual let you change the name.

Is my only option to remove the Id property altogether and implement it separately in each individual child class, assuming I want the option to rename it SomethingId ("Something" being whatever the PK of the one-to-one table is).

Comment: Why do you need to overwrite "Id" in order to add tables with 1-1 relationships?

Comment: Lets say I have two tables, Person and Address, the convention is for Person's PK to be "Id" and Address' PK/FK to be "PersonId" - are you recommending that I just leave it as "Id" and specify the relationship through attributes?

Comment: Either that or let `Address` keep its auto-generated `Id` as _just_ a PK and add another `PersonId` field to hold the FK.

Comment: I stepped away for a moment and was leaning toward doing that, but that won't enforce the one-to-one, unless I force the FK to be unique, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to rename something in a child class you can...

```
public class Child : Parent {

    public ChildID { 
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }

}
```

You may need to then override the Id property if you want it hidden, or to apply an attribute like `[NotMapped]`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here - with your method, I still get an Id and then add the ChildId property? Edit: I guess I do understand, it just seems convoluted as hell, but my question is convoluted, so that figures. Will try it and come back to accept the answer. Ty.

Comment: You asked how to rename the parent class's `Id` property in the child. No?  This lets you do that.  `Id` remains intact for classes that need it, and you can "rename" `Id` in classes that need it renamed.  Yes, using *just* the code above you would end up with two properties (`Id`, and `ChildID`) that pointed to the same data.. but that's what the note is about.. you may need to override the `Id` property if you want to hide it or apply other attributes to it.  *I may have misunderstood the question.  Feel free to clarify if that's the case.*

Comment: No, you understood correctly and answered with what I need. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I re-read my initial reply and it sounded hostile, I apologize for that. I think trying to do what I asked about is a bit silly, in retrospect. That's where "convoluted" came from - definitely my question, not your reply.

Comment: @VSO: It's impossible to judge tone of voice or intent from written word.  I appreciate the response, but rest assured you did not offend.

Comment: @Demodave: this belongs as it's own question.  Asking questions in the comments section is pretty much discouraged around here.  however...  `[Column("customer_id")] public int Id {get;set;}`